# How can I switch my signed in user in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: authentication, visual-studio-2015

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Ultimate (the developer preview edition), under Windows 10. I've already signed in with my own Microsoft account, and when I try to sign in with a 2nd Visual Studio account, I get an error that says I need to perform a switch operation to be able to sign in.

I've tried the following:

- close down Visual Studio
- use the 'search the web and Windows' search box to search for 'Developer Command Prompt for VS2014' ( this is the correct Command Prompt version, at least for the VS2015 preview version anyway).
- right-click this, select 'run as administrator'
- in the command prompt go to to 'c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0, and try the following commands:

`devenv /ResetSettings`
(retains Visual Studio configuration)

`devenv /resetuserdata`
(removes Visual Studio configuration)

Answer (score 5):

I fixed this by deleting a key in my Windows registry:

```
regedit
```

Delete this key:

hkey_current_user\software\Microsoft\VSCommon\14.0\clientservices\tokenstorage\visualstudio\ideuser